# How would I divide a given value with only two numbers?

Tags: ruby

I have to divide a number user put in, using only 5 and 3, for example - 
If the user inputs 25 I would get five 5 coins to get to that value , but if the user inputs 111 i would need to get twenty one 5 coins and two 3 coins.

We are trying to get the value user put in, if the user puts in 112 we would use 20 fives and 4 threes

My solution so far has been this

```
puts "How much are you buying?"
x = gets.to_f

case
when x / 5 
x = x/ 5
when x / 3
  x = x / 3
end
 puts x
```

but that isnt the correct way to do that and I am currently a bit stuck, thanks in advance for help

Comment: What about numbers that cannot be expressed as multiples of 3 and 5?

Comment: I think if you read about `modulo` in ruby that should give an idea how to solve it, basically you have to get number and get modulo of it, then dived number by 5 to get count of fives to get and after that divide modulo by 3 to know how many threes you will have, but I do not understand 111 divide by 5 is 22 and 1 left? so it will be 0 threes.

Comment: @noname We want to get the user value in this case the 111, so we take  five 21 times which is 105 and add those two 3's to get 111

Comment: it is a little bit hard to help cause I do not understand the logic behind it.Because in case 112 you will have 21 fives, 2 threes, and 1 will be left.

Comment: @noname in case where we need to get 112, we would use 20 fives and 4 threes

Comment: @Stefan I edited the post so people could understand better

Comment: So, essentially you are solving MINIMIZE(X - 5*a + 3*b)

Comment: @JörgWMittag, you could use an integer linear programming algorithm to implement that, like so: `minimize upper_bound - lower_bound` subject to: 1) `lower_bound <= X - 5*a + 3*b`, 2) `upper_bound >= X - 5*a + 3*b`, 3) `a >=0` and `b >=0` and 4) `a` and `b` are integer-valued. The problem is that ILP algorithms can take seemingly forever to solve even relatively small problems (or can solve them quickly), nothing like linear programming codes in term of solution times. I think either enumeration or dynamic programming are the right tools here, depending on the size of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So from what you are saying I understand you need method which look something like this.

```rb
def get_change(number)
  rest = number % 5
  puts " 5x#{number / 5} 3x0" if rest == 0
  puts " 5x#{(number / 5) - 1} 3x2" if rest == 1
  puts " 5x#{(number / 5) - 2} 3x4" if rest == 2
  puts " 5x#{number / 5} 3x1" if rest == 3
end
```

I know code is ugly and can be refactored by I want show you the idea behind what you want to achieve. I think that help. Not sure if code 100% work the way you want, but you at least have an idea what and how to do your stuff.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the values you're asking you first have to ask yourself how to solve the problem without programming language. In this case this can be done by following the following steps:

1. Reduce the input number by `3` as long as the resulting number doesn't dip below `0` or until the number can be divided by `5`. Count the amount of times this can be done.
2. Count how often the resulting value can be divided by `5`.

This can be worked out in Ruby like this:

```
def calc(number)
  threes = 0
  until number < 3 || (number % 5).zero?
    number -= 3
    threes += 1
  end

  fives, rest = number.divmod(5)

  [fives, threes, rest]
end

calc(111) #=> [21, 2, 0]
calc(112) #=> [20, 4, 0]
```

This answer assumes an absolute input (zero or higher).

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

I assume that the question is as follows: "given a positive integer `tot` and an array of pairs of positive numbers

```
arr = [[a1,m1], [a2,m2],...,[ai,mi],...,[aN,mN]]
```

we wish to find non-negative numbers `n1,n2,...,nN` such that

```
n1*a1 + n2*a2 +...+ nN*aN = tot
```

and

```
mi <= ni, i = 0,...,N
```

or conclude that no such numbers `ni` exist (can't make exact change).
 Suppose:

```
tot = 104
arr = [[25,4],[10,5],[5,1],[3,4]]
```

`arr` would be interpreted as the change-maker having 4 quarters, 5 dimes, 1 nickle and 4 treys, a "trey" being a coin worth 3 cents.

One solution would be:

```
n0 = 3
n1 = 2
n2 = 0
n3 = 3
```

as

```
3*25 + 2*10 + 0*5 + 3*3
  #=> 104
```

It is actually no more difficult to solve this problem than the one where there are no constraints on the numbers of each coin available.

**Approach to be taken**

The straightforward approach is to consider all combinations of `0..m1, 0..m2,...,0..mN`, looking for one that has a value of `tot`. For `arr` above that would be:

```
(4+1)*(5+1)*(1+1)*(4+1)
  #=> 300
```

combinations. That's easily manageable, of course, but if there were 10 coins and 9 of each coin available that would generate `10**10` combinations.

They other approach, which I present below, is to view it as a dynamic programming problem, the stages being the coins and the states being the remaining amount of change that must be made. The computational complexity to that approach is O(`tot*(m1+m2+...mN)`).

**Code**

```
def make_change(tot, arr)
  return nil if tot.zero?
  chg = arr.each_with_object([tot=>0]) do |(coin, nbr_avail),a|
    if a.last.key?(0)
      a << { 0=>0 }
    else  
      a << hash_for_coin(coin, nbr_avail, a.last)
    end
  end
  return nil unless chg.last.key?(0)
  chg.shift
  recover_solution(arr, chg)
end
```

```
def hash_for_coin(coin, nbr_avail, last_coin) 
  last_coin.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
    (0..nbr_avail).each do |n|
      break if n*coin > k
      h[k-n*coin]=n
    end
    return { 0=>h[0] } if h.key?(0)
  end
end
```

```
def recover_solution(arr, change)
  return nil if change.nil?
  remaining = 0
  (arr.size-1).downto(0).with_object({}) do |i,h|
    coin = arr[i].first
    nbr = change[i][remaining]
    h[coin] = nbr
    remaining += coin*nbr
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [[25,4],[10,5],[5,1],[3,4]]
```

```
change = make_change(104, arr)
  #=> {3=>3, 5=>0, 10=>2, 25=>3} 
change = make_change(85, arr)
  #=> {3=>0, 5=>0, 10=>1, 25=>3} 
change = make_change(7, arr)
  #=> nil
```

```
arr = [[1000,6],[100,7],[25,6],[10,4],[5,2],[3,4]]
```

```
change = make_change(5863, arr)
  #=> {3=>1, 5=>0, 10=>1, 25=>6, 100=>7, 1000=>5}
change = make_change(5972, arr)
  #=> nil
```

**Explanation**

Note that the method returns a solution as soon as it finds one.

For the first example above (`make_change(104, arr)`) it is found that the value of `chg`, immediately before executing `recover_solution(arr, chg)`, were as follows:

```
chg
  #=> [{104=>0, 79=>1, 54=>2, 29=>3, 4=>4},
  #    {104=>0, 94=>1, 84=>2, 74=>3, 64=>4, 54=>0, 79=>0, 69=>1,
  #      59=>2, 49=>3, 39=>4, 29=>0, 44=>1, 34=>2, 24=>3, 14=>4, 
  #       4=>0, 19=>1,  9=>2},
  #    {104=>0, 99=>1, 94=>0, 89=>1, 84=>0, 79=>0, 74=>1, 69=>0,
  #      64=>1, 59=>0, 54=>1, 49=>0, 44=>0, 39=>1, 34=>0, 29=>1, 
  #      24=>0, 19=>0, 14=>1, 9=>0, 4=>1},
  #    {0=>3}]
```

Let's first consider `chg[0]`, which corresponds to quarters:

```
chg[0]
  #=> {104=>0, 79=>1, 54=>2, 29=>3, 4=>4}
```

This tells us that of the total, `104`, `104` remains to be changed if `0` quarters are used, `79` remains if one quarter is used (`104-25`), and so on.

Next examine `chg[1]`, for dimes:

```
chg[1] = 
  #=> {104=>0, 94=>1, 84=>2, 74=>3, 64=>4, 54=>0, 79=>0, 69=>1,
  #     59=>2, 49=>3, 39=>4, 29=>0, 44=>1, 34=>2, 24=>3, 14=>4,
  #      4=>0, 19=>1, 9=>2}
```

This tells us that 104 can be left by using zero dimes, 94 can be left by using 1 dime, and so on. Consider `19=>1`, which tells us that 19 can be left if 1 dime is used. Adding 10 to 19 tells us that the balance was 29 before applying that one dime. We now see that `chg[0][29] #=> 3`, which tells us that 3 quarters were used in addition to one dime to reduce the total to 19.

On to the nickles!

```
chg[2]
  #=> {104=>0, 99=>1, 94=>0, 89=>1, 84=>0, 79=>0, 74=>1, 69=>0, 64=>1,
  #     59=>0, 54=>1, 49=>0, 44=>0, 39=>1, 34=>0, 29=>1, 24=>0, 19=>0,
  #     14=>1, 9=>0, 4=>1}
```

Let's look at `49=>0`, meaning that 49 can yet be changed if no nickles are used. We see how many dimes and quarters were used as follows:

```
chg[1][49+0*5]  #=> chg[1][49] #=> 3 dimes
chg[0][49+10*3] #=> chg[0][79] #=> 1 quarter
```

Could 1 nickle have been used? Of course! Since `104-49 = 55` we could have instead used 2 quarters, no dimes and one nickle. Check it out:

```
chg[1][49+1*5]  #=> chg[1][54] #=> 0 dimes
chg[0][54+0*10] #=> chg[0][54] #=> 2 quarters
```

In fact, during the calculations at one time `chg[2][49]` would have equalled `1` and later overwritten to `2`, only because it was easier to overwrite the value than to check if `chg[2]` had a key `49` and leave the value unchanged if it did (either way works). In larger problems the values of keys may be overwritten many times, which is what keeps the calculations from expanding exponentially.

Lastly, we look at `chg[3]`, the treys:

```
chg[3]
  #=> {0=>3}
```

telling us that 3 treys can be used to bring the balance down to zero. A solution is therefore

```
chg[2][0+3*3]  #=> chg[2][9]  #=> 0 nickels
chg[1][9+0*5]  #=> chg[1][9]  #=> 2 dimes
chg[0][9+2*10] #=> chg[0][29] #=> 3 quarters
```

If fact, as soon as it is found that change can be made, the hashes are reduced to a single key-value pair whose key is zero (as seen above for `chg[3]`). If we executed:

```
make_change(25, arr}
  #=> {3=>0, 5=>0, 10=>0, 25=>1}
```

we would find:

```
chg
  #=> [{0=>1}, {0=>0}, {0=>0}, {0=>0}]
```